# Hiding "People Results" in Search Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, query-rule

I'm wanting to hide the "People Results" from my search results using the Search web part.

How do I go about doing this? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What you are viewing is a `Promoted Results` block. It is enabled by default via a query rule named `People Name in SharePoint Search` which defines a people promoted results for Local SharePoint Results.

If you dont want to see these results, you need to make it inactive.

To do that, you need to go to `Site Collection > Site Settings > Query Rules` in the search section.

[image]

After that, select the result source.

[image]

Here, select the People Name in SharePoint Search" rule and make it inactive as below:

[image]

After the above steps are done, the people promoted results will be not displayed after a couple of minutes. If you are impatient like me, just reindex the site collection !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like somebody thinks that the people group is a good idea, as they have added a query rule to that effect.
See this for details https://support.office.com/en-us/article/understanding-query-rules-8ca2588d-9dc7-45aa-90a4-428d4d695d07

Comment: Yep, that is an out of the box People match rule.